# D3.js add nested data to parent group

Tags: d3.js

I have a 'parent' rectangle which has been drawn around smaller rectangles. [Here's a live example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOjoGO)

The data looks like this:

```
var allData = [{x:50, y: 60, height: 40, width: 30, 
                  defects: [
                { x: 53, y: 61, width: 10, height: 10 },
                { x: 55, y: 71, width: 10, height: 10 },
                { x: 60, y: 76, width: 10, height: 10 }]},
              {x:150, y: 160, height: 50, width: 40, 
                  defects: [
                { x: 151, y: 165, width: 5, height: 5 },
                { x: 160, y: 169, width: 5, height: 5 },
                { x: 165, y: 170, width: 5, height: 5 }]
              }];
```

As you can see, there are 2 rectangles each with 3 smaller rectangles in it called defects.

I'm trying to visualize it but want to do it in 1 selection so I can transform it easier later on.

Here's what I got so far:

```
var svg = d3.select('#test svg')
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 500);

var groups = svg.selectAll('.defect-group')
      .data(allData)
      .enter()
      .append('g').attr('class', 'defect-group')
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'defect-area')
      .attr('width', function(d) {return d.width})
      .attr('height', function(d) {return d.height})
      .attr('x', function(d) {return d.x})
      .attr('y', function(d) {return d.y});

var defects = groups.selectAll('.defects')
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.defects;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'defect')
  .attr('width', function(d) {return d.width})
  .attr('height', function(d) {return d.height})
  .attr('x', function(d) {return d.x})
  .attr('y', function(d) {return d.y});
```

The result of this is:

[image]

As you can see, I (accidentally) nested the defects inside the 'rect' elements. Since a rect cannot have child elements I would like to put the defects also in the 'defect-group' group, I've tried but can't seem to figure out how to put those in the parent group.

How to do this?

Comment: Trying to do it in 1 big block of chained code I don't think is the right way to do it. You won't be able to access the group easily (without having a parent return). I'd recommend splitting into 2 sections of code, merging the selections later if need be.

Comment: Hi Ian, I've updated the code + example. But the same problem persists. Could you tell me how to get those inner rects into the parent group?

Answer (score 1):

Just get the g element out and append everything to that.

In your code, change

> ```
> var groups = svg.selectAll('.defect-group')
>       .data(allData)
>       .enter()
>       .append('g').attr('class', 'defect-group')
>       .append('rect')
>       .attr('class', 'defect-area')
>       .attr('width', function(d) {return d.width})
>       .attr('height', function(d) {return d.height})
>       .attr('x', function(d) {return d.x})
>       .attr('y', function(d) {return d.y});
> ```

to

```
var groups = svg.selectAll('.defect-group')
        .data(allData)
        .enter()
        .append('g').attr('class', 'defect-group')

groups
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'defect-area')
        .attr('width', function (d) { return d.width })
        .attr('height', function (d) { return d.height })
        .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x })
        .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y });
```